# how to fix The requested URL was not found on this server. while other computer can access

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

there are two computer unable to access the web application via the given ip. while other device can access it. the screen says

> The requested URL was not found on this server.

this happens in my computer when i typed the usual web app url at the browser bar e.g  `111.101.165.6/theapp` ..but when other computer typed the same thing. they can access that particular url...but in my case, that url not found error appears and i get redirected to a custom module inside the app  e.g `111.101.165.6/themodule` . strange that only two computer cannot access the correct url. how to fix this ?

Comment: Check the web server configuration

Comment: which one from the webserver should I check? it's running wamp by the way

Comment: Check both - then change the configuration on the one that doesn’t work to match the one that does.